# order by not able to work

Tags: xml

I have a xml file like below, and i wanted to group the toyID and get the sum of how much that toy has been sold. and order it by the toyID with the highest sales.but the code that i wrote is able to sum the amount of toy sold,but the order by the highest amount of toy sold is not working.can i know which part i did wrongly?

```
 ToySale.XML
 <toySale companyID="1" toyID="11" >
   <amount>15</amount>
 </toySale>
 <toySale companyID="3" toyID="11" >
   <amount>12</amount>
 </toySale>
 <toySale companyID="1" toyID="22" >
   <amount>3</amount>
 </toySale>
 <toySale companyID="2" toyID="33" >
   <amount>7</amount>
 </toySale>
```

below is the code that i wrote:

```
for $t in distinct-values(ToySale.xml")//@toyID)
return <toyID>
            toyID : {$t} 

          <totalSale>{sum(for $sum in (ToySale.xml")//toySale
                     order by $sum/@toyID/../amount     
                     where $t=$sum/@toyID
                     return $sum/@productID/../amount)  }

           </totalSale

        </toyID>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This query**:

```
   for $vId
     in (/*/toySale/@toyID)
                     [index-of(/*/toySale/@toyID, .)[1]]

    let $vSales := /*/toySale[@toyID eq $vId]

    order by sum($vSales/amount) descending

   return
     <sale toy-id="{$vId}" total="{sum($vSales/amount)}"/>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<toySales>
    <toySale companyID="1" toyID="11" >
        <amount>15</amount>
    </toySale>
    <toySale companyID="3" toyID="11" >
        <amount>12</amount>
    </toySale>
    <toySale companyID="1" toyID="22" >
        <amount>3</amount>
    </toySale>
    <toySale companyID="2" toyID="33" >
        <amount>7</amount>
    </toySale>
</toySales>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<sale total="27" toy-id="11"/>
<sale total="7" toy-id="33"/>
<sale total="3" toy-id="22"/>
```

---

**An equivalent and slightly shorter query**:

```
   for $vId in distinct-values(/*/toySale/@toyID)

     let $vSales := /*/toySale[@toyID eq $vId]

     order by sum($vSales/amount) descending

    return
       <sale toy-id="{$vId}" total="{sum($vSales/amount)}"/>
```

Comment: thanks alot.learned new things. dint know that we can use aggregate functions on order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
(:
     Find total sales of each toy sold!

     I tried this query here!   http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo
 :)
let $xml := (
    <toySales>
        <toySale companyID="1" toyID="11" >
            <amount>15</amount>
        </toySale>
        <toySale companyID="3" toyID="11" >
            <amount>12</amount>
        </toySale>
        <toySale companyID="1" toyID="22" >
            <amount>3</amount>
        </toySale>
        <toySale companyID="2" toyID="33" >
            <amount>7</amount>
        </toySale>
    </toySales>
)

let $toy-sales := $xml//toySale
for $toy-id in distinct-values($xml//@toyID)
let $total-amount-sold := fn:sum($toy-sales[@toyID = $toy-id]/amount)
return (

   element toy-sale {       
        attribute toy-id { $toy-id },
        text { 
            fn:concat("Total amount sold: ", $total-amount-sold)        
        }
   }
)
```

returns

```
<toy-sale toy-id="11">Total amount sold: 27</toy-sale>
<toy-sale toy-id="22">Total amount sold: 3</toy-sale>
<toy-sale toy-id="33">Total amount sold: 7</toy-sale>
```

xquery #1 the best ^^